# How to install OS X on KVM?

Tags: macos, unix, virtualbox

I need to run an OS X to run Xcode to submit my project written in Cordova. I am using an Linux laptop and I think the best choice is to use KVM to run a virtual machine of OS X, since KVM has the best performance comparing to VirtualBox.

I tried to install it but it looks like KVM does not support dmg image file.

Can any one give some reference on how to install OS X on KVM?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about using OS X in violation of its SLA.

Comment: @dspjm You may salvage your question by mentioning that your laptop is a MacBook (Pro/Air) with Linux only installed. [KVM & OS X](http://kernelpanik.net/running-mac-osx-yosemite-on-kvm/)

Comment: @klanomath, From the single user non commercial perspective there is a dual-requirement, in that is must be Apple-branded hardware **and** that is already running the software, which means it can only be virtualized under a running occurrence of OS X on Apple-branded hardware.  So saying something like "laptop is a MacBook (Pro/Air) with Linux only installed" doesn't make it permissible and is still a violation of the OS X SLA!

Comment: @user3439894 You are looking at the question from a legal viewpoint. I lean towards taking a more technical position. The Apple SLA indeed doesn't allow to use a Type-1 hypervisor only. In a dual-boot environment it may be allowed though. On the other hand parts of the SLA may be legally void in the OP's country. - At the same time: [OS X in VMware ESXI](http://blogs.vmware.com/guestosguide/guest-os/unix-and-others/mac-osx) I don't know how to assess and evaluate the legal facts here.

Answer (score 2):

You are free to virtualize the OS X operating system on a Mac based host.

Virtualizing OS X is only allowed on Apple-branded hardware that is already running the software, otherwise it is a violation of the OS X Software License Agreement. See [Software License Agreements](http://www.apple.com/legal/sla/) for more details.